# rails 4 - wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) - stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error in my rails app when I run it locally:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
     8:         %link{href: "/assets/favico.png", rel: "icon"}/
     9:         %link{href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700", rel: "stylesheet", type: "text/css"}/
    10:         = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" 
    11:         = javascript_include_tag "application"
    12:         = csrf_meta_tags
    13:         = yield(:head)
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___410024948890833714_70223805533300'
```

I have deployed the app on heroku and there are no issues. This issue occurred recently after I updated from rails3 to rails 4.

Instead of using the helpers, adding the tags manually works:

```
%link{href: "/assets/application.css", media: "screen", rel: "stylesheet"}/
%script{src: "/assets/application.js"}
```

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21834563/308731, it could be something in your scss files that is causing this, since it happened after an upgrade from 3 to 4.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have tried an empty application.css file and still get the same error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

i'm assuming you are using sprockets 2.12.0, if that's the case, downgrade it to 2.11.0 as per https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/540

Comment: thanks for the link! the combination of the following worked for me: gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2' and gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'

Comment: I am now getting this after upgrading to Rails 4.0.9.  I have sprockets 2.11.0 and sass-rails 4.0.3.

Comment: Turns out it was the https://github.com/schneems/sprockets_better_errors gem.  It's only supported to Rails 4.0.5.

Comment: @cman77 thanks for the info about sprockets_better_errors - I'm using rails 4.1.4 and ruby 2.1.3 and after downgrading sprockets, I was still getting the error. Removing sprockets better errors gem solved the issue for me. :+1:

Comment: sprockets_better_errors functionality has been incorporated into Rails 4.1, and is no longer needed: https://github.com/schneems/sprockets_better_errors/issues/25

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the updated gems, which have in their instructions to change **application.css** to **application.css.scss**, won't recognize 'application' as a parameter for a scss file for stylesheet_link_tag.  You need to change:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css.scss', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

This will allow you to work with the latest gems.

Comment: This solution is looking for `application.css.sass.css` in my case. Tested with Rails 4.2

Comment: Appears to break `Started GET "/javascripts/application.css.scss.js` ... `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application.css.scss.js")`. Rails 4.2.

Comment: Brent.  For JavaScript it would just be the full name of your JavaScript file.  Not your style sheet file.

Comment: That solved my problem. Using   Rails 4.2.6,  sprockets 3.5.2, turbolinks 2.5.3.  Will do some deeper investigation on that.

Comment: it was `application.css` in my case (although the file is called `application.css.scss`)